# Composer update - Script cache:clear returned with error code 255

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

My `composer update` command is returning an error. The problem is coming from `vendor` folder. I downloaded skeleton project for Symfony 5 and everything seems to be set right.

This is my error in console.

[image]

I tried clearing cache folder and deleting vendor folder, than starting command again, but no luck.

Also, when I do `composer update --no-scripts` as suggested below and docker up the project I get the same error when I try to access it. [project browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhyPK.png)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked where that constant was defined?

Answer (score 0):

welcome on Stackoverflow.

It could happens with some vendor folder when vendor does not implement receipes on flex. Because of error during cache clearing, the composer reinitialized your vendor directory.

You should configure the bundle of vendor. To do that, launch composer update, but do not launch scripts.

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

The vendor directory will be copied and won't be anymore deleted.
Then configure the bundle of vendor.
Then execute the cache command manualy.

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

or

```
symfony console cache:clear
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. :) I tried composer update --no-scripts
 and everything runs ok then php bin/console cache:clear and it throws exact same error. :/

Comment: Yes it is, but now you can configure the bundle of the new vendor

Comment: As I am new in Symfony can you give me some hint how to do that. I don't quite understand.. @AlexandreTranchant

Comment: Have you added a new package or have you only install a new symfony project?

Comment: It's a new project. @AlexandreTranchant

Comment: I never encountered this issue during installation. Could you edit your question and detailed command you have launched to create your project, your php version and your os?

Answer (score -1):

1. Delete vendor folder
2. Delete composer.lock
3. Delete var/cache
4. Run the composer install command.

If you trying for fresh new pimcore, this might work.

Comment: Thank you for replay. Tried, error still the same. :/  @KarthiKeyan

Comment: @JoniJon can you paste the steps which you have followed for installation?

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - as given in the question, the vendor folder has already been cleared. Additionally, deleting `composer.lock` should not be done unless really neccessary